# Orientdb - Match - "The command has not been executed"

Tags: orientdb

I have a Orientdb Database with 2 vertex

Pesquisador with 1 million records

Publicacao with 1 million records too

and an Edge COLABORA_COM with 6,239,382

I need select thousand researchers with the highest number of publications.

I execute the command

```
SELECT  psq1.psq_nome AS nomePesquisador, COUNT(pub1) AS qtdPub
FROM (
  MATCH 
    {class:Pesquisador, as:psq1}.outE("PUBLICOU").inV(){as:pub1}
  RETURN psq1, pub1
)
GROUP BY psq1
ORDER BY qtdPub DESC, nomePesquisador
LIMIT 1000;
```

then thera are the error "The command has not been executed"

if I limit the MATCH RETURN to 250000 records (RETURN psq1, pub1 LIMIT 250000) the match execute with no errors

is there an error of memory?

Comment: could you please post the server logs? Is there any significant info there?

Comment: 2016-07-25 10:13:42:416 INFO  {db=dbCemMilM01} Storage data recover was completed [OLocalPaginatedStorage]
2016-07-25 10:14:23:130 INFO  {db=dbCemMilM01} [TIP] Query 'SELECT FROM Pesquisador' returned a result set with more than 10000 records. Check if you really need all these records, or reduce the resultset by using a LIMIT to improve both performance and used RAM [OProfilerStub]

Comment: the parameters part1: java -server  -Xmx1024m  -Djna.nosys=true -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=512g -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -Drhino.opt.level=9 -Dprofiler.enabled=true -Dstorage.diskCache.bufferSize=4096 -Djava.util.logging.config.file="C:\orientdb/config/orientdb-server-log.properties" -Dorientdb.config.file="C:\orientdb/config/orientdb-server-config.xml" -Dorientdb.www.path="C:\orientdb/www" -Dorientdb.build.number="2.2.x@rf5282664db9300ef3358fb4d7e2066ad418c2e61; 2016-07-08 12:30:59+0000"

Comment: the parameters - part 2: -cp "C:\orientdb\lib\*;C:\orientdb\plugins\*"  com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServerMain

Comment: There is issue on github about huge query results, the milestone is set to 3.0 version: github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/2425

Comment: if a execute witin MATCH da query execute normally SELECT out.psq_nome AS nomePesquisador, COUNT(in.@rid) AS qtdPub
FROM Publicou
GROUP BY out.psq_nome
ORDER BY qtdPub DESC, nomePesquisador
LIMIT 1000;